# DM a specific user with discord.js with options in a slash command

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js, bots, token

today i was trying to make a /warn command that DM the warned user, but when i do that i see an error saying : "Expected token to be set for this request, but none was present"
could anyone help me ?

there is my code :

```
const { SlashCommandBuilder, PermissionFlagsBits, messageLink, Client } = require('discord.js');
const { GatewayIntentBits } = require('discord.js');
const client = new Client({ intents: [GatewayIntentBits.Guilds] });


module.exports = {
    data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
        .setName('warn')
        .setDescription('Choisi une qqun à warn.')
        .addUserOption(option =>
            option
                .setName('cible')
                .setDescription('Le membre à warn')
                .setRequired(true))
        .addStringOption(option =>
            option
                .setName('raison')
                .setDescription('La raison du warn'))
        .setDefaultMemberPermissions(PermissionFlagsBits.BanMembers)
        .setDMPermission(false),
        async execute(interaction) {
            const target = interaction.options.getUser('cible');
            
            await client.users.send(target.id, 'vous avez été warn.')
            await interaction.reply(`${target.username} warn`);
        },
};
```

Comment: i forgot to say that this file is in a folder named commands and that it is not the main file but only a file who contains one command

Comment: Can you add your command handler as well?

Answer (score 0):

you just need to do

```
let raison = interaction.options.getString('raison');
if (!raison) raison = "No raison provided.";
try { 
target.send(`vous avez été warn. \n> Raison: ${raison}`)
} catch (e) { interaction.reply({content: 'couldn\'t dm user his DMs are closed', ephemeral: true}) }
```

Comment: I am glad it did !